# Дана таблица из 10 строк и 5 столбцов

Tags: c#

> Дана таблица из 10 строк и  5 столбцов. Определить: В какой строке находится значение с порядковым номером n, если нумерацию вести построчно сверху вниз, а в каждой строке – слева направо;

помогите пожалуйста, пишу на с#.

Comment: В какой строке находится значение с порядковым номером 13?

Comment: Нарисуйте таблицу ручкой на бумаге, пронумеруйте ячейки по порядку, подумайте.

Comment: Если ответ ниже был пролезен, вы можете принять его, для этого нужно поставить зеленую галочку слева от ответа.

Answer (score 3):

Для начала стоит отметить, что здесь помогают решить проблемы, если Вы что-то делаете, но у Вас не получается. Вы же просите полностью решить за Вас. Это **не ок**.

С другой стороны, новичку можно и помочь :) У всех, кто с этим не согласен, заблаговременно прошу прощения! Вспоминаю себя в самом начале изучения программирования. Любая помощь была на вес золота.

Давайте я не буду писать решение, а просто будем рассуждать. Хотя в конечном итоге рассуждения есть решение. Ну да ладно.

У нас есть таблица. Давайте заполним ее. Я заполню числами от 1 до 50. Получается, порядковый номер будет равен числу под этим номером. Мне кажется, такой вариант проще воспринимается.

```
      1   2   3   4   5
      6   7   8   9   10 
      11  12  13  14  15 
      16  17  18  19  20
      21  22  23  24  25 
      26  27  28  29  30
      31  32  33  34  35
      36  37  38  39  40
      41  42  43  44  45
      46  47  48  49  50
```

Теперь нужно придумать, как найти в нем число с заданным порядковым номером. Допустим, мы не пишем код на c#, а смотрим на бумажку и решаем задачу мозгами. Можно поступить так: пробегаемся глазами по всем числам слева направо, сверху вниз. Находим нужное, смотрим, в какой строке оно находится. Все, задача решена.

С самым примитивным алгоритмом определились. Летс го писать код.

Для начала я написал тесты (подход TDD). Первые тесты были простейшими, но потом я переделал тест так, чтобы он прогонял все числа из нашего диапазона и проверял правильность работы метода поиска строки. Листинг теста я пока приводить не буду, т.к. он сразу покажет, как решить задачу в одну строчку. А нам это не надо. Мы ведь просто рассуждаем.

Создаем массив, который будет соответствовать нашей таблице

```
        private readonly int[][] _tableArray = { 
            new int[] {1,  2,  3,  4,  5 },
            new int[] {6,  7,  8,  9,  10},
            new int[] {11, 12, 13, 14, 15},
            new int[] {16, 17, 18, 19, 20},
            new int[] {21, 22, 23, 24, 25},
            new int[] {26, 27, 28, 29, 30},
            new int[] {31, 32, 33, 34, 35},
            new int[] {36, 37, 38, 39, 40},
            new int[] {41, 42, 43, 44, 45},
            new int[] {46, 47, 48, 49, 50}
        };
```

Каждый элемент массива - это строка, которая состоит еще из одного массива - это числа в столбцах.

Пишем реализацию метода поиска номера строки. Методу передаем порядковый номер, в ответ получаем номер строки.

```
    public int GetRowNumber(int number)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < _tableArray.Length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < _tableArray[i].Length; j++)
            {
                if (_tableArray[i][j] == number)
                {
                    return i + 1;
                }
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Первый цикл for перебирает строки. Заходим в первый цикл. В нем перебираем все числа (это второй цикл for). Если нашли соответствие, то переменная i из первого цикла - это и есть номер строки. Только строки в цикле получаются пронумерованы от 0 до 9, а не от 1 до 10. Поэтому к i прибавляем 1 и возвращаем это значение, т.к. продолжать бегать по циклам нет смысла. Если в первой строке порядковый номер не найден, то выйдем из вложенного цикла, перейдем на вторую строку и повторим поиск. Ну и так далее.
Если порядковый номер по каким-то причинам вообще не найден, то вернем 0 (тут можете сами придумать, как поступать в этом случае).

Все, **задача решена**.

А теперь посмотрим на мой тест.

```
    [Fact]
    public void GetRowNumber_CheckReturnedValue()
    {
        // Arrange
        TableHandler tableHandler = new TableHandler();
        int rowNumber;

        for (int i = 1; i <= 50; i++)
        {
            rowNumber = ((i - 1) / 5) + 1;
            Assert.Equal(rowNumber, tableHandler.GetRowNumber(i));
        }
    }
```

А вот и красивое и **простое решение** :)

Например, ищем, в какой строке находится число с порядковым номером 35.
Давайте считать, что строки нумеруются от 0 до 9, а столбцы от 0 до 4. Тогда 35 превращается в 34. Если разделить 34 на 5, получим 6,8. Но мы пользуемся типом int, значит дробной части не будет. Получается, что число с порядковым номером 35 (в нашем понимании 34) будет в строке 6. Но чтобы вернуть номер строки обратно в диапазон от 1 до 10 (чтобы это стало понятно людям-непрограммистам), мы прибавляем к шестерке единицу. Значит число с порядковым номером 35 будет находиться в 7 строке.

Получается, вот оно, решение:

```
return ((number - 1) / 5) + 1;
```

Надеюсь, я не напрасно потратил свое время. Как говорится, пока объяснял, сам наконец-то понял :)

Успехов в изучении программирования!